# C# Getting/Setting BIOS Settings?

Tags: c#, windows-7, bios

I work with a Dell XPS M1710. The laptop has lights in the lid, the side speakers, and the front speakers (3 sets of lights that can be individually adjusted) and a light under the mousepad. In the BIOS I can change the color of these lights, at least, each group. Also, I can turn a light on/off under the mousepad, I can't change it's color, just alternate if it's lit. The laptop came with a lot of software from Dell, but I've installed Windows 7 and lost all of their apps, including one that allowed me to change these light colors. Now that Dell's app is gone, I'm interested in making my own C# application to change the color of these 3 sets of lights (I don't particularly care to change the light under the mousepad, I like it off). How would I go about developing an app to retrieve and change these BIOS settings?

Comment: Can you make a better title? This doesn't really describe what you're trying to do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We released an SDK for the community:

http://www.dell.com/html/global/xps/lightfx/index.html

(I can say "we" because I worked on it!!)

- Offers an extensive library of
  functions for building custom effects
  using the XPS M1710 LED lights.
- Allows you to build custom effects
  just by creating a text file with a
  few simple XML tags -- even if you
  are not an XML programmer.
- Includes application programming interface
  (API) functions that allow you to
  program lighting effects directly
  into applications.
- Highlights
  several sample effects to inspire you
  to new heights of creativity.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've been able to find, this hackery is done in SMBIOS.

Looks like [this developer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=616864) figured it out -- he's written a Python GUI on Linux.

I read the source, and he's hooking to dellLEDCtl in libsmbios to do the dirty work.  [Here's the source, if you can stomach it.](https://fedorahosted.org/libsmbios/browser/src/bin/dellLEDCtl.cpp) The git repo that Dell provided to the community for this stuff [is here](http://linux.dell.com/git/?p=libsmbios.git;a=summary).

I don't think you're going to get this done completely managed.

Comment: I think you can throw keeping pretty much any of the actual work as managed code, you're going to need inline assembly to invoke the INT BIOS call.  If he's never done that before, it could be a fun learning experience.  But if he just wants to get it done, it'd probably be easier to track down whatever Dell app he's missing from their website.